# an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)

Tags: hibernate, db2

2023-10-13 05:25:23,212 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: insert into CPP.ItemAnalytics (id, dateCreated, dateUpdated, action, itemFK, mostCurrent, personFK) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-10-13 05:25:23,237 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (default task-28) SQL Error: -803, SQLState: 23505
2023-10-13 05:25:23,238 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (default task-28) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;ITEMANALYTICS, DRIVER=4.32.28
2023-10-13 05:25:23,258 ERROR [org.hibernate.AssertionFailure] (default task-28) an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.harley_davidson.rex.domain.analytics.ItemAnalytics entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Comment: Duplicate key . This is a FAQ. Find the row that already exists with the duplicate , and decide how to recover, e.g delete, merge, etc